# interface and object inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, queue

I have this following code snippet.

```
Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
queue.add(N);
Node curr = queue.remove();
```

`removeFirst()` is a method of LinkedList. `remove()` is a method of Queue. Queue is the interface and LinkedList is the object that implements the queue. From what I have learned, when you declare an object as type interface and then assign it to a new object, that object must implement all the methods in the interface and can have other methods that are not specified in the interface. Now, `removeFirst()` is a method not specified in the Queue interface, but it is specified in the LinkedList class. However, when I call removeFirst(), I get an error saying "Cannot find symbol." What am I miss understanding? Both the Queue and LinkedList are from Java's util library. I am using this to write a BFS method.

Comment: ?? you are calling `removeFirst()` on an interface that does not have the method's signature ?? and it is strange that you got a syntax error "Cannot find symbol." ?????

Comment: Why did I get a down vote? I don't understand. Did I ask the question in the wrong way or am I being down voted because this is an easy question? Because if so, then this site is advocating that it's only for smart people.

Comment: didn't down-vote you , but still your question is kind of basic and at the same time can be very complicated to answer. not sure if it fits SO. hope that the already posted answers are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `queue` is of type `Queue` so when you access your object through it, you can only use features that are in the `Queue` interface. The fact that it's 'really' a `LinkedList` means that it *has* the extra methods, but the fact that you're treating it as a `Queue` means you're effectively promising not to use them.

If you were to create a `LinkedList` variable and point it at the same object, you'd see the `LinkedList` methods.

The point of this is that your code that uses this interface doesn't need to change if you change the concrete type of the list later in the life of the project, as long as the new type you use still implements `Queue`. By acting as though `removeFirst` doesn't exist, the compiler makes sure you don't shoot yourself in the foot from the perspective of future maintenance by using features not all queues necessarily will have.

Answer (score 3):

- `Queue<Node> queue` is the **compile-time type** of the variable `queue`.
- `LinkedList` is **runtime type** of the variable `queue`.

The compiler checks (at compile-time) if the runtime-type you're trying to assign is compatible with the compile-time type (`Queue<Node>`). And since `LinkedList` is actually a sub-type of `Queue`, the compiler allows the assignment.

However, the compiler **does not have any evidence** that at Runtime, `queue` will expose a method called `removeFirst()`, because the actual assignment is done when the `Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();` statement is reached. The only thing the compiler is sure about is that `queue` will have the abstract methods defined in the `Queue` interface *available* -- that is why it allows calling *only* those.

Potentially, it is completely possible that `queue` changes its runtime-type to something that does not expose a `removeFirst()` method before the `queue.removeFirst()` statement is executed (e.g., some thread changes it to an `AbstractDeque` - another sub-type of `Queue`, which does not have a `removeFirst()` method).

If you are, however, absolutely sure that `queue` will have a `removeFirst()` method at Runtime, you could do a cast:

```
((LinkedList<Node>)queue).removeFirst();
```

which is not really clean, and then you should think about if `Queue` is the right compile-time type of the variable.

Comment: I understand this, but then my question becomes, when implementing software engineering patterns like factory, adaptor, etc, there are often cases where we declare a variable as its interface but assign it to a new Object. We call both object-specific methods and interface methods on this new object. How is this possible? Is my question clear? Also, why is my question being down voted? I believe I followed the correct format, provided relevant code, provided my own research, and was very specific. I think it's very rude to down vote someone just because this is an easy question for others.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is of type `Queue` and in general it is not clear at compile time that the actual object behind it is a `LinkedList`, even if it seems obvious in this particular case. Therefore the compiler has to consider this as an error.

But you can tell the compiler that you are sure that the object is a `LinkedList` by using a cast:

```
((LinkedList<Node>)queue).removeFirst();
```